# replaceing std::string with const char*

Tags: c++

I was wondering could someone please help me implemenrt this method whereas I dont need to use std::string.

The method takes in tewo parameters, one for char array and the other one is the size of the char array.

The parameters passed will be an array of differernt values seperated by commas, e.g. "Rule1,Rule2,Rule3,Rule4,AT,T,Cat,Dog".

The member variable "m_rulesSet" is a std::string constaining simular values. I want to compare the both to check if the "name" is within the std::string "m_ruleSet"

```
bool 
Matche(const char *str, size_t strSize)
{
    std::string target(str, strSize);

    if(m_ruleSet.empty())
    {
        return true;
    }
    if((NULL == str) || (strSize <= 0))
    {
        return false;
    }

    const char * ptr =0;
    const char * start = target.c_str();

    while ((ptr = strchr(start, ',')) != 0)
    {
        std::string name(start, ptr - start);
        if(name ==m_ruleSet)
        {
            return true;
        }
        start = ptr + 1;
    }
    if(*start)
    {
        std::string name(start);
        if(name==m_ruleSet)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Please any help would be appreciated, thank you so much in advance

Comment: What is this method supposed to do? Where are you having problems?

Comment: Actually, it should be quite the opposite. You should *want to* use `std::string` instead of C strings.

Comment: @netcoder: Obviously, `std::string` is not always the best choice. Especially if this function is one of the bottlenecks in the application.

Comment: What if he wants to target a platform where using STL isn't practical? (e.g. Android until recently)

Comment: I need rid of the std::strings for performance reasons, I have updated my example above to explain what its for

Comment: From my experience, most performance issues from using STL strings come from using STL strings in a bad way. Like, from what I can see, in the above code.

Comment: `m_ruleSet` contains "values"?  As in, more than one?  Your existing code tries to match the whole thing.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you're trying to do? It seems like it could be a lot easier...

Comment: @netcoder: It sure sounds like: "I have a list of comma-separated fields inside a counted string.  I also have a second string.  I want to know if the second string appears in the list."

Comment: @BenVoigt: That sure probably be easier, and faster, with a proper STL container. Even in C, you'd want to avoid parsing a long string to find a match and use a linked list or something instead.

Comment: @netcoder: It might be faster, since you can skip directly to the next item instead of scanning for the comma.  But you lose locality.  So which performs better is going to be hardware-dependent.  STL container would definitely be easier.  Binary search in a presorted container should be faster yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you simply mean replacing `std::string` comparison by `strcmp` or `strncmp` (as this is the only thing you use the `std::string` for, everything else is already using C-strings)? Well, if you really want it:

```
bool Matche(const char *str, size_t strSize)
{
    if(m_ruleSet.empty())
        return true;
    if(!str || !strSize)     //remember that size_t is unsigned by standard
        return false;

    const char * ptr, start = str;
    while (ptr = memchr(start, ',', strSize))
    {
        size_t len = ptr - start;
        if(len == m_ruleSet.size() && !strncmp(start, m_ruleSet.c_str(), len))
            return true;
        strSize -= len + 1;
        start = ptr + 1;
    }
    return *start ? (strSize == m_ruleSet.size() && 
                     !strncmp(start, m_ruleSet.c_str(), strSize)) : false;
}
```

Like Ben points out in his comment and answer, you need to use `memchr` instead of `strchr` when you got an additional size argument and your string is not neccessarily zero-terminated.

You may also want to replace `m_ruleSet` by a C-string (to get rid of the `.c_str()`), but I actually question the need for replacing `std::string` by C-strings in C++ code in the first place.

Comment: @ChristianRau: You might get some hints from my answer.  `strnchr` is spelled `memchr`.

Comment: We are still using the std::string m_ruleSet. How is `strcmp(start, m_ruleSet.c_str())` better that `m_ruleSet == start`?

Comment: @BoPersson I didn't know there was an overload for directly comparing a `std::string` to a C-string, I thought this would convert the C-string to a `std::string` (which the OP wants to prevent).

Comment: And you just made the final column use a prefix match instead of a complete match.  This problem is deceptively hard.

Comment: @BenVoigt I freak out! I want my damn `std::string` back!

Comment: Wait, no, actually they're all prefix matches now.

Comment: @BenVoigt Ok, what next? I just don't want to give up and delete this goddamn answer, but your version is actually much cleaner.

Comment: I think that's it, although I'd check the length for equality, for a tiny efficiency improvement (and arguably better readability)

Comment: @BenVoigt Realised this myself the moment you posted this comment.

Comment: Oh wait, when did you get rid of `strncmp`?  You still need to pass the length, after checking it.

Comment: @BenVoigt I don't think so, doesn't `c_str` guarantee zero-terminatedness? Ah, I looked it up in the standard (C++11). `c_str()+i` is equal to `[i]` for `i` in `[0,size()]` and for `i==size()` `[i]` returns `char()`, so `strcmp` is safe after the size comparison.

Comment: @ChristianRau: Yes it does, and that NUL will not match the comma at `*ptr`.

Comment: @BenVoigt Ah I see, the search is false when the sizes (determined by the NUL) don't match. Sorry for overlooking that and thanks again for pointing it out. This really looked much easier at first. Man, god bless our good old `std::string` ;)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're just using a `std::string` to hold a substring and then compare it.  Making a copy in order to do substring comparison IS inefficient.

Instead of

```
std::string name(start, ptr - start);
if(name ==m_ruleSet)
```

you could write

```
if (ptr - start == m_ruleSet.size() && 0 == strncmp(start, m_ruleSet.c_str(), ptr-start))
```

You also should be using `memchr` and passing in `str` and `strSize`, instead of making `target` a `std::string`.

My overall advice would be to use a proper lexer / grammar recognizer, like flex+bison.  That will generate an optimized DFA even faster than separate calls to `strchr` and `strncmp`.  This is especially valuable if you have multiple strings (rules) to match.

---

But here's a simple DFA:

```
bool csv_match( const char * const haystack, size_t const haystack_size, const char* const needle, size_t const needle_size )
{
    const char * const haystack_end = haystack + haystack_size;
    int state = 0;
    // invariant: state == -1 if the current field doesn't match
    //            otherwise the first (state) characters have been matched
    for( const char* p = haystack; p < haystack_end; ++p ) {
        if (*p == ',') {
            if (state == needle_size) return true;
            state = 0;
        }
        else if (state < 0)
            ;
        else if (state >= needle_size || *p != needle[state])
            state = -1;
        else
            ++state;
    }
    return (state == needle_size);
}
```

Use it like

```
bool Matche(const char *str, size_t strSize) const { return csv_match(std, strSize, m_ruleSet.data(), m_ruleSet.size()); }
```

Comment: thats awesome! can you explain how this would be implemented in memchr?

Comment: @aliaserror: `strchr` needs a NUL-terminated string. `memchr` uses a counted string.  Look at the help page for `memchr` and it should be very clear what changes from `strchr`.

Comment: You could also use a class that does substrings without making copies, the usage of which becomes much more intuitive and readable in my opinion.  [This one](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1StringRef.html) from llvm for example.

Answer (score 0):

[string.h/cstring](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/) provides most methods for string/basic-memory manipulation. You should be able to find replacements for almost all `std::string` methods in it. When you don't find one directly mapping, you can write one yourself using methods from `cstring`. Looking at the code you posted, `strcpy`, `strncpy` (or `memcpy`) are surely needed.

If you have specific questions, add them to the post and someone would help you.

Comment: Doesn't look to me like any copying is needed.  All use of the string is read-only.

Comment: @BenVoigt I meant for creation of `name` and `target`. Of course it might be possible to optimize, but for one to one replacement once can use...

Answer (score 0):

so the methods you use from std::string are

- Char * ctor

`std::string target(str, strSize);`  => `char * target =  strdup(str)` or strcpy

- .empty()

`m_ruleSet.empty()` => `strlen(m_ruleSet.c_str())==0`

- Comparison

`name==m_ruleSet` => `strcmp(name.c_str(),m_ruleSet.c_str()) == 0`

Comment: there is not a one to one mapping from char * to string in terms of functionality.  And unles there is a good reason you don't really need to mix char* and std::string.  the question to me bespoke of not knowing which functions where available for manipulating char *.  the usage mode of c style strings and std::string are totally different .

Comment: Which doesn't change that your suggestion #1 is useless: He can read the input directly, doesn't need to make a copy, #2 is useless, you don't need to measure the length of a string to find out whether it's empty, #3 is wrong, because it looks for a terminating NUL, while we know that the actual input may have a comma.  Unless you make a useless copy first, in order to have a NUL.

Comment: 1. if you pass a char * and length to std:: string it makes a copy of the string.  Same thing

2. strlen == 0 is the same as seeing if the string is empty unless you want to add additional functionally like ignoring whitespace 

3.string1 == string2 is strcmp(str1,str2) == 0 .  You offed ways to redactor the code and change it I just showed how to achieve the same functionality as the std string functions

Comment: And that's why the code is the question is too slow.  Duplicating the behavior using `string.h` won't speed it up.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like rewriting

```
std::string name(start);
if(name==m_ruleSet)
{
    return true;
}
return false;
```

into

```
return m_ruleSet == start;
```

?

There is no need to construct a `std::string` just to compare it to a C string. The == operators of `std::string` will work just fine anyway.

If you need to compare `m_ruleSet` against a substring of another `std::string` or a C string, there are several overloads of `std::string::compare` that does just that.

Comment: I dont fully understand sorry - using "start" would still require me to use std::string(str,strLength)?

Comment: `std::string name(start);` will compute the length of the string pointed to by `start`. So will `m_ruleSet == start`, so it is not necessary to do it separately.

Comment: @Bo: But based on the signature, and the fact that `strSize` is being passed to the constructor, the input is counted rather than NUL-terminated.  Of course, some of the original code won't work if it's not NUL-terminated, so who can be sure?